# Using a .cmd file to launch PowerShell scripts in a Temp folder

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to use a .cmd file to open a PowerShell script (`p.ps1`) in a Windows users temporary folder (specifically `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp`).

However, using `@echo off PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "$env:temp/p.ps1"` errors out as `"$env:temp/p.ps1"` doesn't work with the File parameter.

While hard-coding the path to the PowerShell script works in launching the scripts, the cmd file will not work with separate users or lettered drives aside from mine. Looking for any suggestions on how to get over this hurdle.

Comment: `"%TEMP%\p.ps1"`. You're in cmd's world while you do this, not PowerShell's.

Comment: `$env:temp` at that point in the `-File` parameter of powershell.exe is interpreted by cmd.exe and not PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%TEMP%/p.ps1"
```

Here's some a of other Windows Environment Variables for [CMD.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)